# Jolt Conversion : List of Key/Value to name, value conversion

Tags: json, nested, mapping, jolt

Conversion of the jolt spec. Here we will be having the list of the queryFriendList list inside this we have one more list of object and inside the list we will be having the details in the name value pair that needs to converted.
I have some data in the key value pair that's needs to converted into the id values like `accountId:"885580007377"` and we need to iterate the FF Number 1...10 and form a separate list of object as shown below.

Input jolt spec:

```json
{
  "statusCode": "0",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "responseId": "SubsMgmt989579439429",
  "operationName": "Query",
  "errorMsg": "",
  "queryFriendList": [
    [
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "value": "885580007377"
      },
      {
        "name": "Group Number",
        "value": "FN Group 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "FF Number 1",
        "value": "251808340081"
      },
      {
        "name": "FF Number 2",
        "value": "251808340082"
      },
      {
        "name": "FF Number 3",
        "value": "251808340083"
      },
      {
        "name": "FF Number 4",
        "value": "251808340084"
      },
      {
        "name": "FF Number 5",
        "value": "251808340085"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "value": "56565"
      },
      {
        "name": "Group Number",
        "value": "FN Group 2"
      },
      {
        "name": "FF Number 1",
        "value": "878222222233"
      },
      {
        "name": "FF Number 2",
        "value": "2518083408822"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "accountId": "885580007377",
      "groupNumber": "FN Group 1",
      "detailsList": {
        "FFNumber1": "251808340081",
        "FFNumber2": "251808340082",
        "FFNumber3": "251808340083",
        "FFNumber4": "251808340084",
        "FFNumber5": "251808340085"
      }
    },
    {
      "accountId": "56565",
      "groupNumber": "FN Group 2",
      "detailsList": {
        "FFNumber1": "878222222233",
        "FFNumber2": "2518083408822"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following shift transformation specs :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "queryFriendList": {
        // loop through all the "queryFriendList"
        "*": { // indexes of the array
          "*": { // indexes of the nested array
            "@value": "data[&2].@name" // generate arraywise results
              // while separate the objects
              // by indexes from the array
              // (derived after going 2 levels up)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Acc*": "&2[&1].accountId", // rename this field
          "G* *": "&2[&1].g&(0,1)&(0,2)", // and this one
          "FF *r *": "&2[&1].detailsList.FF&(0,1)r&(0,2)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Above spec looks fine but inside the detailsList its generated formed with space between the words could you please on this?
example: from "FF Number 1" to "FFNumber1" for all the tags?
    "detailsList" : {
      "FF Number 1" : "251808340048",
      "FF Number 2" : "8855990007377",
      "FF Number 3" : "251808340048",
      "FF Number 4" : "22823631891",
      "FF Number 5" : "708990129036"
    
    },

Comment: @DilipNagaraja Excuse me I missed that part, just fixed now.